# Invert mouse wheel scrolling in integrated terminal (VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I invert the mouse wheel scrolling direction for the integrated terminal inside VSCode?

For the editor, I could set it using a negative value:

```
"editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": -0.3,
```

I am trying something like this for the integrated terminal, but it doesn't work (even when reloading VSCode):

```
"terminal.integrated.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": -1,
"terminal.integrated.fastScrollSensitivity": -1,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Xterm.js which VSCode is using for the integrated terminal does not support negative scroll sensitivity settings. What about doing a feature request?

As a side note, you can see that at [this](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/d3fd3d0f2254a966238e575f3505d5cac31cff91/src/browser/Terminal.ts#L851).